# chrome.tabs.sendMessage response not received immediately

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, request, firefox-addon, response

I aim to scrape chats from chatGPT using a Chrome extension. On the link update, I am sending a message to the content script to read the data. Content-writer responds after reading data using the query selector. In the service-worker I am not receiving the data at that time, but if I click on other chats of that page, that previous data is sent after that.

service-worker sends message onupdate

```js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
    console.log("changed to ", tab.url)
    if (changeInfo.status == "complete") {
        if (tab.url.includes("chat.openai.com/c/")) {
            console.log(changeInfo)
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {
                url: tab.url,
                type: 'URL_CHANGE'
            }, (response) => {
                if (response && response.length > 0)
                    console.log('Chat: ', response)
            });
        }
        else if (tab.url.includes("chat.openai.com")) {
            console.log(changeInfo)
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {
                url: tab.url,
                type: 'HOME'
            }, (response) => {
                if (response && response.length > 0)
                    console.log('Home: ', response)
            });
        }
    }
});
```

content-script reads the message and send response accordingly

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    if(request.type === 'URL_CHANGE'){
        console.log(request);
        chats = document.querySelectorAll(".text-base")
        texts = []
        chats.forEach((chat) => texts.push(chat.innerText))
        sendResponse(texts)
    }
    else if(request.type === 'HOME'){
        console.log("Home");
        chats = document.querySelectorAll(".text-ellipsis")
        texts = []
        chats.forEach((chat) => texts.push(chat.innerText))
        sendResponse(texts)
    }
});
```

I am getting the correct/expected response but after another 'link update' not immediately.

Comment: It usually means the actual content is added after the tab has loaded i.e. asynchronously. You can use MutationObserver inside the content script to wait for the elements. BTW instead of chrome.tabs.onUpdated you can use `navigation.onnavigate` event inside the content script i.e. there's no need for the service worker for this specific task.